# How to store the recognized celebrities details to AWS Collection in AWS celebrity recognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

Is there any way in AWS celebrity recognition to add the recognized celebrity faces to the collection.
Like in normal facial recognition we can use the **IndexFaces** operation to detect faces in an image and add them to a collection. In future it gets easier to see if face is already present in our system by searching in collection.
link : [Add face to collection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/add-faces-to-collection-procedure.html)
But I couldn't find similar approach for celebrity, can someone please help the method available that can add the celebrity face to the AWS collection.

To summaries my question does **recognizeCelebrities** method provided by AWS stores the image in collection or not? if not how we can achieve that.